# How to read in file with relative path in Java?

Tags: java, file

I have a file `users.txt` with a file path of `myPlugin/impl/src/main/resources/myPlugin/impl/src/main/java/com/company/myPlugin/impl/users.txt`. I am trying to access this file from a Java class with a file path of `myPlugin/impl/src/main/java/com/company/myPlugin/impl/UserManager`. I don't want to hardcode a path because the working directory will change. I did try:

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + .....path to users.txt;
```

The problem with this is that it only works when I run the plugin locally. When it is deployed on another machine or server, the working directory won't contain all the files. What I really need is a way to open the file using only a relative path from `myPlugin`. I also tried

```
URL path = getClass.getResource("");
```

And then added the rest of the path but this did not work either. Is it even possible to use only a relative path that is not dependent on the current working directory? When I run my plugin on the server, the working directory does not contain the source code or directory structure.

Comment: Would you use maven to build your application, and can you confirm whether it is a web application?

Comment: I do use maven and no it is not a web application.

Answer (score 1):

The file location consists of two parts: `myPlugin/impl/src/main/resources/`  and `users.txt`. The first one is the location where the build system (Maven) finds your resources. The second is your actual resource.

Everything **under** `myPlugin/impl/src/main/resources` (both files and directories) will be copied to your classpath.

To answer your question, your file should be accessible via

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("users.txt");
```

Comment: A small observation: this is assuming the file's location on the classpath is in the same package as wherever getClass().getResource() is invoked from. Which is not the case if I see the question. `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource()` may be the better advice.

Comment: This, which in theory seems like it would work, does not. The path it generates is the correct path from the "/target/class" directory, but the file can't be found by the program.

Comment: @Gimby Given that the resource is in the default package, your correction is essential. Thank you.

Comment: Oh hold on - what is that `impl` directory? You'd normally have `myPlugin/src/main/resources` May be you need `myPlugin/src/main/resources/impl/users.txt` ?

Comment: I think (untested) that `getClass.getResource("/users.txt")` could also work (search from root of classpath).

Comment: I added more of a directory structure to the path of the resources; following the usual syntax the company uses. The getClass.getClassLoader().getResource() method returns null and when I add a "/" to the resource name to be found, it also causes null issues. However, without the backslash it does get the correct path from the class directory created by the maven build

Comment: getClass.getResource() worked!